# The exception unknown software exception (0x40000015) occurred in Monero Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, wallet-recovery

I have ~6.5 Monero coins stuck in this wallet ... I get this error plus and error that says the Daemon isn't working.

I have no clue what's going on or how to fix this problem. 
I'm on v12.2(not 12.3 command line).
I've left it overnight and re-installed the wallet. But it still won't synch with the blockchain.

1) I don't think it's a virus because two of my machines are seeing the same problem - one is a sandboxed machine that doesn't really touch the internet. so unlikely this is the issue.
2) I'm running windows 10
3) Haven't had issues prior to 2 weeks ago (but the same issue occurred with v12.0 so I upgraded to 12.2 and still the Daemon doesn't work)

Any help is greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Have you tried launching `monero-wallet-gui.exe` as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use the latest release 0.12.3: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/releases

Also, as dEBRUYNE mentioned in a comment, try running as administrator.